# Detect if DivX and MKV codecs are installed or not?

Tags: windows, video, detection, divx, mkv

How can we detect, within a program, whether DivX and MKV codecs are already installed or not?

For my apps, I need to check user OS (Windows) for some requirements. Are there any specific registry keys that I can check? Or should I check for file association of these types? What's the best solution?

Comment: MKV is not a codec. It is container for video, audio and subtitles streams. You should be more specific what you are trying to achieve. Are you want to check if user has any application that can play avi, mkv. or you want to check codecs (xvid, divx, H.264, theora) availability.

Comment: I need to check codecs availability.

Comment: Like Zuljin said, MKV is not a codec.  It's not even a video format.  It's a video container that can contain a lot of different things.

Comment: Check those 2 links http://tanvon.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/enumerating-directshow-filters/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375617(v=vs.85).aspx
This can help you in displaying all available DirectShow Filters that are used by Windows Media Player to display videos

Answer (score 0):

Include a dummy video in your resources that is similar to the video content you want to play, then try to load it off-screen; if it works, you know that the codecs are correctly installed *for the format you care about* (i.e. both the container and video/audio codecs are there, and they are working)